# Http GET Request to a php file is sending empty string in parameters

Tags: delphi

I'm trying send a GET Request with parameters for a php file, but these parameters are  receiving empty string in php file. So, how solve it?

Here is my Procedure for send of a Get Request with parameters.

```
procedure REQUST();
Var
Resposta: TStringStream;
TSConsulta : TStringList;
post : TIdHTTP;
msg : String;
begin
Resposta   := TStringStream.Create('');
TSConsulta := TStringList.Create;
post := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
try
post.Request.UserAgent:='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36';
msg := 'http://localhost/file.php'+'?plugin='+GBPlugin+'&user='+UserName+'&so='+GetSOComputer;
post.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
post.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
post.Get(msg, Resposta);
finally
TSConsulta.Free;
post.Free;
Resposta.Free;
end;
end;
```

And here is my php file.

```
<?php

$user = $_GET["user"];
$plg = $_GET["plugin"];
$so = $_GET["so"];

//------------------------

echo "User: ".$user; # Delphi sends empty
echo "Plugin: ".$plg; # Delphi sends empty
echo "SO: ".$so; # Delphi sends empty

?>
```

Comment: Are GBPlugin, UserName and GETSOComputer buit-in variables in Delphi? Because I don't see where you are setting their values in the code you provided.

Comment: @bitfiddler, are functions that returns a string.

Comment: @DaviReis: That does not guarantee that they are not returning empty strings, though. Did you *verify* that? What does their code actually look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make sure your string values are not empty to begin with.  Most likely, they actually are.
2. make sure the values you are constructing the URL with are properly url-encoded, in case they contain reserved characters that are not allowed to appear unencoded in URLs.

   ```
   msg := 'http://localhost/file.php?plugin=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(GBPlugin) + '&user=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(UserName) + '&so=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode(GetSOComputer);
   ```
3. setting the `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentType` and `TIdHTTP.Request.Charset` properties is useless in this situation as they is not used in a `GET` request.  They would make more sense in a `POST` request instead.
4. you can use a packet sniffer like Wireshark or Fiddler, or assign one of Indy's `TIdLog...` components (`TIdLogFile`, `TIdLogEvent`, etc) to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property.  You will be able to see exactly what `TIdHTTP` is actually sending.
5. on the PHP side, you can output the value of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to see what PHP is actually receiving before parsing it into `$_GET`:

   ```php
   <?php

   $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
   $user = $_GET["user"];
   $plg = $_GET["plugin"];
   $so = $_GET["so"];

   //------------------------

   echo "Query: $query\n";
   echo "User: $user\n";
   echo "Plugin: $plg\n";
   echo "SO: $so\n";

   ?>
   ```

Comment: `TIdURI.ParamsEncode` was the solution. Thank you very much!